# Python Improve List Compare Speed

Tags: python

I need help improving the script speed, at first it works fine, but the more the scripts runs the slower it gets I always have to restart it over to get full speed. So I really need to find a way to speed it up.

How the script works:

1. It opens up saved .txt files `skus_local` (~100-400k lines) + `keywords_local` (~2million+ lines)
2. It gets url,category (~10k lines file) and loops for each url,category steps 3,5,6 so it's repeated process.
3. The script will scrape 2 lists `new_skus` (400 values) + `new_keywords` (1k max values)
4. The script will check `new_skus` with `old_skus` and a new `upload_skus` created with unique values.
5. Same for `new_keywords + old_keywords`
6. script will append to file `upload_skus and`upload_keywords`

I can see that steps 4,5,(6 maybe) when comparing causes the speed problem

```
        try:
            f = open(settings['skus_local'],"r")
            old_skus=f.read().split("\n")[:-1]
            f.close()
            del f
        except:
            old_skus=[]
            f = open(settings['skus_local'],"w")
            f.close()
            del f
        skus_local_file = open(settings['skus_local'],"a")

        try:
            f = open(settings['keywords_local'], "r")
            old_keywords=f.read().split("\n")[:-1]
            f.close()
            del f
        except:
            old_keywords=[]
            f = open(settings['keywords_local'], "w")
            f.close()
            del f
        keywords_local_file = open(settings['keywords_local'],"a")


        csv_reader_counter = 0
        for category, url in csv.reader(fp):
            if not (csv_reader_counter == fp_counter):
              csv_reader_counter = csv_reader_counter + 1
              continue

            print url,category

            new_skus, new_keywords = ScraperJP.main(url)

            upload_skus=[]

            for sku in new_skus:
                if sku not in old_skus:
                    upload_skus.append(sku)

            del new_skus

            if upload_skus!=[]:
                insert_products.main(settings['admin_url'],settings['username'],settings['password'],upload_skus,category)
                for sku in upload_skus:
                    skus_local_file.write(sku+"\n")
                    old_skus.append(sku)
                skus_local_file.flush()
                del upload_skus

            upload_keywords=[]

            for urls in new_keywords:
                if urls not in old_keywords:
                    upload_keywords.append(urls)
            del new_keywords

            if upload_keywords!=[]:
                for keyword in upload_keywords:
                    keywords_local_file.write(keyword+"\n")
                    old_keywords.append(keyword)
                keywords_local_file.flush()
            del upload_keywords

            csv_reader_counter = csv_reader_counter + 1
            fp_counter = fp_counter + 1
            fl = open('lineno.txt',"w")
            fl.write(str(fp_counter))
            fl.close()
            gc.collect()

        os.remove('lineno.txt')
        skus_local_file.close()
        keywords_local_file.close()
        fp.close()
        del skus_local_file
        del keywords_local_file
        del fp
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Use sets instead of lists. The `del` are not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the information in [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects).

To check for new content you just need `new_skus - old_skus`.

So instead of lines like:

```
for sku in new_skus:
    if sku not in old_skus:
       upload_skus.append(sku)
```

You can use `new_skus.difference(old_skus)` which will give elements in `new_skus` but not in `old_skus`.

If you want to store the set, you can use pickle.

```
import pickle

s = {1,2,3,4}
with open("s.pick","wb") as f: # pickle it to file
    pickle.dump(s,f)

with open("s.pick","rb") as f1:
    un_p = pickle.loads(f1.read()) # unpickle and use

print un_p

set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

You can also append objects to one file:

```
s2 = {4,5,6,7}

import pickle

with open("s.pick","ab") as f:
    pickle.dump(s2,f)


with open("s.pick","rb") as f1:
    s1 = pickle.load(f1)
    s2 = pickle.load(f1)
    print s1,s2
set([1, 2, 3, 4]) set([4, 5, 6, 7])
```

Example of using sets:

```
s1={1, 2, 3, 4}
s2={4, 5, 6, 7}
s3={8,9,10,11}
print s1.difference(s2)
print s1.union(s2,s3)
set([1, 2, 3]) # in set 1 bit not in set 2
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]) # all elements in s1,s2 and s3
```

You can add contents of one set to another using:

```
s1.update(s2) #  add contents of s2 to s1
print "updated s1 with contents of s2", s1
updated s1 with contents of s2 set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

Comment: @MarkVoidale, I added an example to my answer.

Comment: thank you this is awesome, I will change my code to use sets. I have one question only. Right now my code will open `skus_local and keywords_local` once and have it opened all the time for the loop to use the list, Is it possible the better approach is to open it every loop? Basically open pickle dumb make the difference close it, and repeat or open picklde dumb once make the difference add the pickle list more information and every loop make a difference while it's always open?

Comment: I have not studied your code too much but I imagine you should be able to load the pickle objects, do the work needed and dumps at the very end with the updated data. If you use the methods you have available through using sets, you will be able to do most of what you need in a few lines of code.

Comment: is it possible to append to same set? I saw it's 2 different sets or you have to combine it? What if i have x,xxx of them? I just want 1 set

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks I will take a look, I will also suggest to use cPickle it's much more faster.

Comment: The bottleneck in the OPS code was not the pickling but yes cPickle is faster.

Comment: @Padraic This is funny today I was suspicious that difference doesn't delete duplicates. And I wasn't aware of this behavior of 2 different sets I thought it will load both of them, my mistake read your example too quickly. So how should I append and union at the same time? First load set from file and then append? There is no way to append to existing set right? Thank you.

Comment: @zumbamusic, I added code to update s1 with the contents of s2. You will never have duplicates in a set.